# How can I use Jenkins to detect the presence of a file on an SFTP server?

Tags: jenkins, sftp

I want to use Jenkins to monitor an SFTP site, and fire off a build when a given file type appears on that site.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in that case you should have 2 jobs.

First job - running every N minutes with a bash script as a build step:
`wget ftp://login:password@ftp.example.org/file.txt

Then you should have https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin , which runs on condition when file "file.txt" (downloaded or not downloaded previously) exist

Afte that you can trigger your next job in case if file exist (or do anything else)

Answer (score 0):

Like in the previous answer I would use two jobs but instead of bash scripts I would use python and and sftp since it makes dealing with ssh a bit easier. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp